# Django payments guide

Tags: django

I am trying to make my own payment gateway django application.I went through many payment gateway websites like paypal, razorpay. But I'm facing issues like how the processing should be and how the workflow should be.

I just need to integrate this with my other website, so this is secondary preference.so i need help that how can I create payment gateway django application.Any resources for the same or any online prebuild Github/Gitlab etc repository available.

I have some experience in django but i need to do this project within 10 hours.
I need to implement very basic functionality of what payment gateways does. No need to api. Just locally I will connect my payment gateway app to my other website.

I just want to show how payment gateway work locally means creating my own very basic payment gateway app. Credit card details etc will be fake. No real money transaction.

Remember: fake payments and I just want to develop and show how payment gateway work. A basic local app. Without real payment thing but virtual and fake.

Comment: This question is way too broad as it is, but in my opinion one of the easiest ways to accept payments (if that's what you're looking for; it's hard to tell) is to use Stripe. They provide a JavaScript frontend for entering credit card info and a Python library to execute payments etc.

Comment: @AKX Thankyou Sir but without using stripe. Just local aplication.What i mean is what stripe does i need to impliment that.

Comment: So you want to accept credit card payments without any external provider? Can't be practically done.

Comment: @AKX sir,I will create model for fake cards and store some money and will transfer to service provider model while payment and it will be deducted from customers account so no real money transfer is taking place .So no real credit card is required.

Comment: Right. Your original post didn't specify you were looking for a fake solution. The classic model for something like this is that once the payment is accepted, rejected or canceled, the gateway redirects the user back to the "merchant's" application with signed URL parameters, which the merchant's software can decode to ensure the message is from your gateway, and act accordingly (e.g. set the order/whatever as paid).

Comment: @AKX no real payments sir.I want to show this thing in my project.Like suppose amazon allows payments from paypal so when someuser buys any product from paypal then paypal deducts user money and adds to amazon's money.